# Hot to set a date value in a sqlpl request?

Tags: plsql

I am trying to update many registrations in my database but I don't know how to write the requests for dates, I used:

```
UPDATE XX SET date_creation = 09/06/2016 WHERE date_creation = 01/01/2016;
UPDATE XX SET date_creation = '09/06/2016' WHERE date_creation = '01/01/2016';
UPDATE XX SET date_creation = date(09/06/2016) WHERE date_creation = date(01/01/2016);
```

But this resulted errors.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DATE LITERALS properly :)

```
UPDATE XX 
 SET date_creation = to_date('09/06/2016','MM/DD/YYYY') 
 WHERE date_creation = to_date('01/01/2016','mm/dd/yyyy');
```

Comment: Thank you, and how to wrire a request including a date column using where date_creation?